# Convert iPhone app to universal app: Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am using xib-s for my `UITableViewCells` on iPhone. Now I need to convert my app to universal app. Do I have to create new xib-s (looking exactly the same way) for the iPad version? My current problem is that I am using grouped `UITableViews`. As the left and right margins on both devices differ, some of the controls on iPad are partly "out of the cells".

In case I need new xib-s (looking exactly the same way), do I need separate properties for the controls in the `ViewController`? For example, for a label named `myLabel`, do I need a second property `myLabelIpad` or is there a better way to handle that?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First understand what you are up to. How do you want your iPad app to look like? How does it navigate. Ceratinly you want to leverage from the lager screen of the ipad. When ever you do that and the auto-resizing mechanism is not sufficient (which it rarely is) then go for a separated xib file.

Second - for each XIB which hosts the same number and types of UIView and UIConrol subclasses, you should be able to use the same view controller for two separate XIBs. Just link all conrols within both XIB to the related IBOutlet properties and IBAction methods alike.

However, when you take leveraging from iPad capabilites seriously then you are like to end up with a different set of view controllers. That is when you can combine the controls of several iPad views wihin one single iPad view and similar cases.

Nevertheless, think of using popups. The content of a popup could nicely correlate to what is a full screen on the iPhone. In that case you can use the same view controller again within that popup container.

Does this sort of answer your question? If not, then please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you. All answers of the question are great but that is the one that summarizes all the info that I needed.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to create new xib. But if there are small changes , then you can maintain one xib. However it depends on how different your iPhone / iPad versions are. For example, if the iPad version is just a bigger version of the iPhone one with a few extra buttons, etc, it's easier to use one UIView and just set the frames of the subviews appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can retain the same Table cell xib files. You just have to get the Auto resizing masks of the cell and its subviews right.

Comment: I have selected "Autoresize Subviews" in the IB but that doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: Ya that is fine. You have to set the Autoresizing masks. Refer Apple docs http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5

Comment: You can do that in the XIB itself.

Comment: I was not really able to set the autoresizing masks appropriately. I ended up creating new xibs. Maybe not the best solution right now but it allows me changing the iPad version later on.